# Python Multicast between client and server will only work with router between them

Tags: python, sockets, multicast, python-3.8

I'm new to Python sockets and with multicast in general.
I have seen here and other places different codes to do Multicast and I'm using one of does codes
The client code is on a Windows 10 at the moment- in the future it should be able to run on Windows, linux and macOS.

The server will run on linux -Ubuntu 16.04 at the moment but should also run on ubuntu 20.04 in the future-

When I run both codes at my computer (Windows 10) the communication works.
When working in two separate computers or devices it will only work if there is a router between them.

Connecting them with a strait cable and static IP will not work even if there is PING between both devices in both directions. -server can ping the client and client can ping the server-

How can I see the UDP multicast packets when connecting both devices with a cable without a router between them?

Currently I'm using the following codes for test:

- Code for client

```
    import socket
    import sys
    
    message = b'very important data'
    multicast_group = ('224.1.1.1', 10000)
    
    # Create the datagram socket
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    
    # Set a timeout so the socket does not block indefinitely when trying
    # to receive data.
    sock.settimeout(5)
    
    ttl = 1
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, ttl)
    
    try:
        # Send data to the multicast group
        print(sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message)
        sent = sock.sendto(message, multicast_group)
    
        # Look for responses from all recipients
        while True:
            print(sys.stderr, 'waiting to receive')
            try:
                data, server = sock.recvfrom(16)
            except socket.timeout:
                print(sys.stderr, 'timed out, no more responses')
                break
            else:
                print(sys.stderr, 'received "%s" from %s' % (data.decode("utf-8"), server))
    
    finally:
        print(sys.stderr, 'closing socket')
        sock.close()
```

- Code for server:

```
    import socket
    import struct
    import sys
    
    multicast_group = '224.1.1.1'
    server_address = ('', 10000)
    
    # Create the socket
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    
    # Bind to the server address
    sock.bind(server_address)
    
    # Tell the operating system to add the socket to the multicast group
    # on all interfaces.
    group = socket.inet_aton(multicast_group)
    mreq = struct.pack('4sL', group, socket.INADDR_ANY)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
    
    # Receive/respond loop
    while True:
        print(sys.stderr, '\nwaiting to receive message')
        data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    
        print(sys.stderr, 'received %s bytes from %s' % (len(data), address))
        print(sys.stderr, data.decode("utf-8"))
    
        print(sys.stderr, 'sending acknowledgement to', address)
        sock.sendto(b'ack', address)
```

Thank you in advanced for your help.
Best regards,

Comment: It's an wifi connection? I guess wifi doesnt propagate multicast, and on ethernet depends on the manufacturer

Comment: geckos, thank you for your reply.
It is not a WiFi network, it is a cable network.
As mention direct connection between the devices will not work, but having a router between them it will work,
I need it to work also with direct connection, no router, between them.

Comment: oh, *without* a router between them, I read that wrong, sorry, you want a kind of point to point multicast with is a bit of nonsense, I'm not sure if is possible either since multicast depend on multicast routing, you may want to try to transform one of the ends in the multicast router, IDK, anyway is a very interesting question

Comment: I strongly against tldp.org because they tend to be very out dated, but, the theory should still be valid and it should point keywords that would help you on your saga https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.multicast.html good lucky

Comment: anyway, my real recomendation is that you use something like netmask /28 for point to point networks and handle this in the application, and abstract the communication in its own layer, otherwise you will endup with very unreliable manual setups of multicast point to point, this if you're running this as production

Comment: with /28 networks you are sure that there is only one other at other side of the network, you can even infer its ip address from yours

Comment: @geckos thank you for your reply.
I'll take a look at it.
The idea is to have a discovery tool.
I will not know the server IP address or subnet and the client may be on a total different subnet.
The idea is for the server to send via multicast a message with his information: IP, subnet, getaway, etc. This way the client will get this information and configure the computer accordingly to establish communication.

Comment: You seems to be reimplementing the zeroconf

Comment: gecko, appreciate all your help and patience with this issue.
Just took a quick look at zeroconf and see that is only for the client side
the issue here is that I'm creating both the server and the client side.
The sever will be install at a device that will be send to a client.
This client can change the IP of the device and as we al know may forget what the IP is.
When a technician comes to do service to the device, he will not know what the IP of the device is, so with this discovery tool he will be able to quickly find it.
the technician will not have access to the command line

Comment: Cool project, anyway you will need to create a kind of probe device, zeroconf depends on muticast too, you should me able to discover server and client by issuing an mdns request to the network, but youre still stuck with multicast. Do you control the client and server boxes OS installation? If so you may be able to set multicas in an reliable way

Comment: Here is a cool post telling about multicast without router https://www.smallnetbuilder.com/lanwan/lanwan-features/30343-multicasting-and-the-small-network-part-2

Comment: geckos, once more thank you for you patience and help.
I'll take a look at what you have recommend me.
Yes, we are responsible and control the OS that will be installed on the boxes.